# В прерывании ISR(USART_RX_vect) получаю только 4 байта(символа) на atmega328p по USART

Tags: c, avr, atmel-studio

Коллеги, доброго времени суток.

Подскажите что делаю не так. Изучаю работу прерывания ISR(USART_RX_vect) микроконтроллера atmega328p. С помощью терминала (terminal 1.9b) отправляю данные по COM порту. Если отправляю 4 байта на микроконтроллере то все 4 байта получаю, но если отправляю больше, так например 10 байт на микроконтроллере ловлю первые 3 байта и 1 последний байт сообщения.

Обратил внимание что в принципе захожу в метод ISR(USART_RX_vect) всего 4 раза независимо от того сколько байт(символов) отправляю. К примеру передаю символы ':123456:789', в результате на микроконтроллер приходит ':129'

Подскажите что упускаю? Что делаю не так? Заранее спасибо!

**Код приема сообщения на микроконтроллере**

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define BAUD_PRESCALE 3 //3 - 256000 U2X=0

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define FRAME_SIZE 32
#define FRAME_CARRET_RETURN 13
#define FRAME_LINE_FEED 10
#define FRAME_COLON 58

volatile bool isReading = false;
volatile uint8_t modbusRxBuffer[FRAME_SIZE];
volatile uint8_t modbusTxBuffer[FRAME_SIZE];
volatile uint8_t modbusRxBufferIndex;
volatile uint8_t modbusTxBufferIndex;

void blink10() {
    PORTB |= ( 1 << PINB2 ); 
    _delay_ms(50);
    PORTB &= ~( 1 << PINB2 ); 
    _delay_ms(50);
}

void USART_Init() {
    /* Enable receiver, transmitter, and interrupt on receive */
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<TXEN0) | (1<<RXCIE0);
    /* Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit */
    UCSR0C = (1<<USBS0) | (3<<UCSZ00) | (0<<UMSEL00);

    UBRR0L = BAUD_PRESCALE;
    UBRR0H = BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8;

    sei();

    modbusRxBufferIndex = 0;
    modbusTxBufferIndex = 0;

    // Задержка не менее 20 миллисекунд согласно документации после инициализации.
    _delay_ms(20);
}

ISR(USART_RX_vect){
    blink10();

    uint8_t status = UCSR0A;
    uint8_t data = UDR0;

    if (data == FRAME_COLON) {
        if (!isReading) {
            modbusRxBuffer[0] = data;
            modbusRxBufferIndex = 1;
        } else {
            modbusRxBuffer[modbusRxBufferIndex] = data;
            modbusRxBufferIndex = 0;
        }
        isReading = !isReading;
    } else if (data == FRAME_LINE_FEED) {

    } else if (data == FRAME_CARRET_RETURN) {

    } else {
        modbusRxBuffer[modbusRxBufferIndex++] = data;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    DDRB = 0xFF;

    USART_Init();

    while(1){

    }
}
```

Comment: с виду вроде бы всё нормально... что делается в `main`'е в этот момент? что делают `blink*`? как именно проверяешь, что пришло на контроллер? в общем весь код в студию...

Comment: Отредактировал свой код. (выложил полный текст кода)

Comment: Вопрос к функции blink. Как быстро она выполняется? Такое подозрение, что это функция мигания лампочкой и она выполняется некоторое время. Это неправильно. Обработчик прерываний должен быть очень быстрым, фактически только заполнять ваш буфер. В противном случае данные будут теряться и будет происходить подобная ситуация. С blink можно поступить следующим образом: в обработчик прерываний устанавливать флаг, а в бесконечном цикле майна проверять этот флаг и мигать светодиодов по мере необходимости.

Comment: @ArchiKu, про `blink` уже сказали — судя по вссему это основная ошибка... Из мелочи: на практике режимы окромя `8N1` и скорости окромя `115200`, `9600` (и некоторых более медленных) используются редко. Это не ошибка, но выглядит как лишнее усложнение, если ничем не обосновано... также avr-gcc умеет делать сразу так: `UBRR0 = BAUD_PRESCALE`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, как только буду у проекта, проверю код без "блинка" и отпишусь!

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да все верно было сказано выше, blink(задержка в нем) был причиной потери части сообщения. Благодарю за рекомендации по скорости и режиму 8N1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В примере в прерывании вызывается `blink10();`

в функции `blink10()` блокируется выполнение на 100 мс при помощи `_delay_ms(50);`

таким образом прерывание выполняется 100мс и не успевает отработать приходящие данные.

Кроме того, из примера не совсем понятно как вы выяснили, что приходят только 3 байта? В примере нет какого-либо вывода полученных данных куда-либо

Comment: Я не один раз запускал этот код, мой blink ранее зависел от того какой символ придет(и загорались разные светодиоды). Собственно в процессе отладки я пытался ответить на 2 основных вопроса - почему приходят только 3 байта и какие байты в итоге приходят. К сожалению сейчас нет возможности проверить работу кода без blink, но как только это сделаю, отпишусь!

Comment: Да все верно было сказано выше, blink(задержка в нем) был причиной потери части сообщения. Для отладки сейчас просто включаю или выключаю светодиод без каких-либо задержек.